# javascript HTML get value

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in my HTML5 code which makes use of javascript:

```
     var myObj = localStorage[dataObj];
     alert(myObj);
     alert(myObj.City);
```

When I do alert(myObj) it shows   {"ID":68,"City":New York} which is what is in var.
I now need to get the value of City. I do the following but it shows as undefined: 
        alert(myObj.City);
I also tried

```
    alert(myObj[0]:City) but that did not work as well
```

Comment: @DanielA.White: If `alert` showed that, it's a string.  If you `alert` an object, you get `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myObj` is a string, it needs to be parsed into an object.

```
myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
console.log(myObj.City);
```

P.S. `console.log` is much better for debugging than `alert`.

Comment: IE doesn't seem to support console.log ?

Comment: @AlanFoster: IE (< 9, I think) only supports it after you open the developer tools (F12).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a string, rather than an object. Load it with:

```
myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
alert(myObj.City);
```